# What is the "quality" of a Wi-Fi access point?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, debian, wifi-driver

In Debian you can use `iwlist` to scan nearby Wi-Fi access points. In the statistics like this:

```
Cell 01 - Address: CC:B2:55:XX:XX:XX
                ESSID:"X"
                Protocol:IEEE 802.11bg
                Mode:Master
                Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                Encryption key:on
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                          9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s
                          48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Quality:33  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : CCMP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                Extra: Last beacon: 252ms ago
```

There is a field called "quality". I can understand what "signal level" means, it is RSSI (Received Signal Strength Indication). However, **what does "quality" mean really? How is it measured?**

Meanwhile, on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS laptop, it is weird because the "signal level" fields of all scanned access points are 0, so are the "noise level" fields. But on my Raspberry Pi which has Raspbian, I can see "quality", "signal level", and "noise level" fields have different readings. (This is not the primary problem, but if you know the answer please just breifly describe a little bit.)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the hardware and the driver.  From `iwconfig` man page:

> **Link quality**
>
> Overall quality of the link. May be based on the level of contention or interference, the bit or frame error rate, how good the received signal is, some timing synchronisation, or other hardware metric. This is an aggregate value, and depends totally on the driver and hardware.

Which explains the difference you're seeing.

If you were to remove the USB WiFi adapter from your Pi and insert it to your Ubuntu laptop (and also disable the laptop's internal adapter) then you'd get useful results on there too.